# Can't solve Runtime error on Android Studio 2.1

Tags: java, android

I'm an Android beginner and I'building a test app to know what I can do and what I can't, and I'm trying to solve this Runtime error and don't know what to do.
Can anyone help me please? I post my code and the error

MainActvity.java:

```
package com.example.android.myapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText uname;

    {
        uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    }

    EditText pword;

    {
        pword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    }

    Button btn;

    {
        btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        OnClickButtonListener();
    }
    public void OnClickButtonListener() {
        btn.setOnClickListener(
                new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.android.myapplication.Activity2");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Log:

```
05-01 14:32:21.725 32378-32378/com.example.android.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.myapplication, PID: 32378
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.myapplication/com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2773)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1434)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:2172)
    at com.example.android.myapplication.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:12)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1690)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2773) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1434) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move all three of your statements like this one:

```
uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
```

into `onCreate()`, after your `setContentView()` call, for two reasons:

1. In general, you cannot safely call methods that you inherit from `Activity` until after `super.onCreate()` has been called
2. You specifically cannot call `findViewById()` until you actually have the views, such as by calling `setContentView()`

Answer (score 1):

Take these three line of code to oncreate method after the setcontentview method recall. That initializes your view and your NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION will not happen.

```
uname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
pword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```